# Nginx Bad Request (400) only with domain name not with IP (gunicorn and django)

Tags: django, nginx, devops, gunicorn

I know many others have asked the same question, but I haven't found any answers that are relevant or work for me. If you do know of a duplication, feel free to direct me to it.. I'm getting lost in the maze of nginx threads!

I am new to this and used the following tutorials to set up my django site with gunicorn and nginx:

https://vahiwe.medium.com/deploy-django-and-flask-applications-in-the-cloud-using-nginx-gunicorn-and-systemd-centos-7-4b6aef3a8578

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

My website works if I access it via the IP address but I get a Bad Request error when I try by the domain name.

In nginx.conf my server block looks like:

```
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     123.456.78.910 mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /var/www/userf/website;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/userf/website/website.sock;
        }
    }
```

My gunicorn.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ssej91D
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/ssej91D/pwebsite
ExecStart=/var/www/userf/website/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --error-logfile - --bind unix:/var/www/userf/website/website.sock website.wsgi:application
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/userf/website/.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And my ALLOWED_HOSTS in django's settings.py:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["mywebsite.com", "www.mywebsite.com", "123.456.78.910"]`
I have not added any SSL related settings to the Django settings file yet.

To test the domain name, I've tried making a test index.html file in another directory (let's call it testwebsite and then changing the nginx.conf to:

```
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     123.456.78.910 mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location / {
                root /var/www/userf/testwebsite;
        }

    }
```

This worked perfectly. My domain name showed index.html.

I've checked the logs, and they are always empty. I'll be totally honest, I just copied all of the proxy server settings from the tutorial and I don't actually understand them. I guess my suspicion is I'm doing something wrong in setting up nginx as a proxy server.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, just to help trace the error, could you set your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `['*']` and then print `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` to console from just about any view? You should get the hostname you used to access Django. Thank you!

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! The server I'm using has a different host name... (I'm sharing it) It works now!

Comment: Happy to help! It always boils down to something like this! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a host in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

The host name of the droplet I'm using is different because I'm sharing it.